# Doc failing to generate multiple actions single operation

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger

I was wondering if anyone has come across a workaround when using `Swagger` / `Swashbuckle 5.0.1` to document a single operation which can have multiple actions against it. For example, take the following:

```
api/products
api/products?productType='cheese'
```

When attempting to generate the docs I get an error suggesting this is not supported. However, the [Swagger](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle#working-around-swagger-20-constraints) docs suggest there is a workaround by doing a merge.

*I don't understand what they mean by this and how to go about doing it. Can anyone provide any information?*

The only workaround I have been able to find as suggested in their documentation is to do the following (resolve using the first entry):

```
c.ResolveConflictingActions(x => x.First());
```

This isn't ideal as from an API perspective I want all the variations present / visible.

Comment: Where you able to figure out how to get multiple actions working with swagger?

Comment: No and apparently on the git page for it this is expected behaviour. I've ditched using it as it's quite buggy and you're forced to adjust the YAML that gets produced.

Comment: @Null this might prove to be helpful https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/142#issuecomment-220498289, other people are experiencing this too.

Comment: I found a similar post on Stackoverflow that suggested to name the overloaded method something different and then simply use the route attribute the define the route.  For example, if I already have 'Get()', then simply name the second method 'GetProduct()'.  Then, I would create a route attribute and set the route to 'api/<controllername>' with the 'HttpGet' verb defined.  That resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in **Swashbuckle** [SwaggerConfig.cs](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/3e97952a45a07f0e4e6881694e91a50f9afc6cb6/Swashbuckle.Dummy.Core/App_Start/SwaggerConfig.cs#L183) file on this setting:

> In contrast to WebApi, Swagger 2.0 does not include the query string
>   component when mapping a URL

This is not a Web API issue here, Swagger 2.0 spec does not actually support having query parameters.

Comment: A case where a swashbuckle.ResolveConflictingActions filter will NOT be called during the API documentation, is when the parameter is called 'id'. Which generates a route of "api/<controllername>/{id}" https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/5489aca0d2dd7946f5569341f621f581720d4634/Swashbuckle.Tests/Swagger/CoreTests.cs#L495